# JSHint - ignore variable that start with a string

Tags: jshint

I am using lots of global constant variables and I don't want to ignore them all one by one, they all start with `TXT_`, and I'd like to know if it's possible to tell my JSHint in the `.jshintrc` to ignore those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, JSHint doesn't support custom rules. There is a [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jshint/M8w5o1fSfI8) asking for this functionality, but the latest activity was 4y back. ESLint was created exactly with this purpose and it also supports all the rules from JSHint, but it way more flexible.
Please check [this rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#varsignorepattern) and see if it helps you.